# Does there exist ten distinct positive integers $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{10}$ such that as follows

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Edit:**

Do there exist ten distinct positive integers $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{10}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 = 19 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} x_ix_{i+1}$? Assume that $x_{11} = x_1$.

I don't know from where to start.

Comment: Do the numbers have to be integers or can they be arbitrary positive reals?

Comment: Yes, integer. I forgot to give "integer".

Comment: @RossMillikan They are positive integers.

Comment: I would start by playing with sets of 2, 3, 4 numbers and see what the possible differences are between the sums. Another starting point would be a spreadsheet with the 10 different numbers as inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying both side by $2$, and rearranging terms, we have:
$$\sum^{10}_{i=1}(x_i-x_{i+1})^2=38$$

This means we only care about the difference between the terms. Note that since the terms are distinct, the difference cannot be $0$. By trying different combination from $1$ to $5$, we find that only $2\cdot 3^2+4\cdot 2^2+4\cdot1^2$ works.

Since they need to be in a loop and distinct, we find that $+3,+2,+2,+1,+1,-3,-2,-2,-1,-1$ works. Then for example, $1,4,6,8,9,10,7,5,3,2$ works.

Comment: When u multiplied by 2, aren't you have $2x_i^2$?

Comment: Then ignore the comment, which I have deleted.  You are right.

Comment: @nyeowNyeow:  Yes, but one goes into $(x_i-x_{i+1})^2$ and the other into  $(x_i-x_{i-1})^2$